# Strange behavior when using HTML form with Lightbox jQuery plugin. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using the following code to send an email without refreshing or navigating to another page. It works great.

However I edit it so that the #thelightboxdiv containing the form to be loaded when the `my button` is clicked, and then the lightbox script opens up and shows the form.

The problem is that when I submit, the page refreshes and nothing happens (and the email is not sent).

How can I fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#myform").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#results")
            .show()
            .addClass("loading").html("");

        $.post('mailme.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#results')
                .hide()
                .html(data)
                .fadeIn('slow')
                .delay(2000)
                .hide(1).removeClass("loading");
        });
    });
});

$('#loader').html('');


    </script>


            <a class="btn1 small lightbox" href="#thelightboxdiv">my button</a>
            <div id="thelightboxdiv" style="display: none!important;">

                    <div id="contact-form" class="contatct-form">
                        <div class="loader"></div>
                        <form id="myform" action="" class="contactForm" name="myform" method="post">
                                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30">
                                    <input id="e-mail" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30">
                                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="button" value="send">
                        </form>
                    </div>
<div id="results"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to include the mailme php in the div to see what happens...

```
<div id="thelightboxdiv" style="display: none!important;">
     <?php include 'mailme.php'; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this works. It sends me an email everytime I open the page